# Update data documents for JWS deployed app

Tags: java, swing, jnlp, java-web-start, application-resource

I have a swing application that uses many data files, these data files will change time to time. How can I load these data files on client's machine? Is there any way to create a folder like structure and run a batch file or so? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"many data files"*  What types of files are they?  What data do they contain?  Are they strictly for read only (on the client-side)?  Are they consumed by other apps. besides yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Assume you want to ship your application with the datafiles, you may embed them as a zip/jar in your application-jar-file.
   Extract the embedded zip to a temporary local file and use ZipFileSystemProvider to extract the content to some place on the disc. 
   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208681/extract-some-content-from-jar-file-downloaded-with-jws/11304705#11304705) is an example how to extract some content from zip/jar-file embedded in a .jar-file downloaded by JWS.
2. Same as 1, but skip the zip stuff and instead provide a list of all the resources you want to extract
3. One other way is to create the files pragmatically using either [java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) (java 7+) or [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. All the data files are in csv format. As of now, there is no restriction on data files. I will try the solution you have suggested.