# Install files onto host computer with JNLP and determine resulting paths

Tags: java, jar, jnlp

I am developing an app (Sigar) that will be available for download through a web browser by clicking on a link. The application will monitor machine info, and it needs some library files to do so (such as libsigar-x86-linux.so,libsigar-x86-freebsd-5.so).

My plan is put the native files into a JAR first, then when the application is downloaded with JWS, I will

- Unpack the JAR file, including the native libraries to a folder
- Find the current class path as determined when the app is running.
- Finally set the java.library.path relative to the classpath, so that my native libraries can be found.

Currently I am trying to determine the path for the JAR using this code:

```
String path = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain()
   .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

But I must be doing something wrong because the path returned is the web service path, and not one in the local environment.

Could anyone point out what mistakes I have in my current plan? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `nativelib` tag in the JNLP-file is designed to take care of any native libraries you need.

See the documentation for the resources tag in the 
[JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html).

Comment: Also Java is not well suited for wrapping native applications.  If all you want is a downloadable Windows application, .NET may be a better choice for wrapper technology.  (ClickOnce perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the native lib in `jnlp` is probably what you are after.

But if for other reasons you want to control the unpacing manually, you could achieve by embedding a `jar` inside a `jar`. see: [Extract some content from jar-file downloaded with JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208681/extract-some-content-from-jar-file-downloaded-with-jws)

Comment: I haven't tested, but I believe that the SecurityManager in place in Java WebStart would not permit trying to load such files as native libraries.

Comment: ive tried it for bundling and launching an .exe with processbuider, when running the jnlp in unrestricted. but havnt tested loading dlls, so you might be right